# Json array return in production with cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp

Hi i have a code that returns a json response in cakephp, it works perfectly in localhost, but in production it gives not well formed json response to parse.
for example here's my action code

```
public function deletepic(){
        ///configuration de l'ajax
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->request->allowMethod(array('ajax'));
        $message = array('key'=>'hello');
        if($this->request->is(array('ajax'))){

            $picid = $this->request->data['id'];
            $picname = $this->request->data['attachmentname'];
           if($this->Profile->deleteAll(array('Pic.id'=>$picid,'Pic.attachment'=>$picname),false)){
               $message = array('info'=>'good');
           }
           else{
               $message = array('info'=>'bad');
           }
        }
        $this->response->type = 'json';
        return json_encode($message, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    }
```

and it returns for me the following json response :

```
 {
    "info"
```

i don't know what's causing this probleme, because the same code works on the local machine

Comment: It may actually having proper details. Your live server system may be truncating printing new lines in log. Try printing `json_encode($message)`

Comment: what does you mean by tray printing json_encode($message)??should i construct json manually instead of using json_encode??

Comment: I mean did you try returning without 'JSON_PRETTY_PRINT', like `return json_encode($message)`

Comment: yes, the same problem happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP have built in JsonView class.You can do something like below.

At your Config/routes.php file, add this line of code:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

and do override your code like this:

```
 public function deletepic(){
            ///configuration de l'ajax
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->request->allowMethod(array('ajax'));
            $message = array('key'=>'hello');
            if($this->request->is(array('ajax'))){

                $picid = $this->request->data['id'];
                $picname = $this->request->data['attachmentname'];
               if($this->Profile->deleteAll(array('Pic.id'=>$picid,'Pic.attachment'=>$picname),false)){
                   $message = array('info'=>'good');
               }
               else{
                   $message = array('info'=>'bad');
               }
            }
            $this->set('_serialize', $message);

        }
```

CakePHP will automatically switch view classes when a request is done with the .json extension, or the Accept header is application/json.

For more info :http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: hi thanks  for your reply , i use now the json extension but $this->set('_serialize',$message); it returns an empty response not like the old one

Comment: after using .json extension, it worked in the production server with this code in the end  $this->response->body(json_encode($message,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); instead of _serialize,

Comment: at your ajax call,did you call the url with .json extension also or not? If you follow the convention ,your code should be good.

Comment: yes, of course now i call it using .json extension in the ajax jquery call. now i follow the convention, the only thind that i didn't is calling the action in the ajax call using .json extension